# Permission denied - PHPMailer

Tags: smtp, composer-php, phpmailer

**EDIT**
Returning to improve my question and make it useful to others.
I had two major issues here:
1) I didn't understand what composer really is and how to use it
2) I didn't realize I had different pieces of my dev stack running under different users/permissions (as one commentor suggested).

All is well after addressing those gaps in my knowledge. Don't copy tutorials blindly without full understanding!

**END EDIT**

I want to use PHPMailer in my cloud based software. I downloaded the PHPMailer library using Composer. I setup the SMTP example code replacing all the particulars with my information in a file called testmail.php. When run the script as a test I get:

> Warning:
>   require_once(/var/www/html/appreciate-erp/vendor/autoload.php): failed
>   to open stream: Permission denied
>   in /var/www/html/appreciate-erp/testmail.php on line 2
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   'vendor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php')
>   in /var/www/html/appreciate-erp/testmail.php on line 2

All the other directories in the `appreciate-erp` directory are accessible by httpd. I have temporarily given `rwx` permissions to all users in `/usr/share/PHP`.  `/Usr/share/pear` doesn't exist from what I can tell.

Please help. Does anyone know what might be going on?

Comment: Did you run `composer install` as root? You may beed to fix ownership rather than permissions.

Comment: I created a special user which I ran Composer install as. The terminal advised against running it as root. I don't fully understand Composer. Is it still needed by the PHPMailer library after installation? I'll try removing PHPMailer and reinstalling as root.

Comment: @synchro I deleted composer and reinstalled as root, like you said. That did it! Now I'm getting an SMTP error but that's probably a wrong password or something. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad it worked but I meant that if you had installed it as root (which you shouldn't), the httpd user might not have permission to access it. I was suggesting you install composer as the web server user.